# JavaFX - How to be sure that an animation is really stopped

Tags: java, animation, javafx, javafx-8

I have a running animation `a` that's doing some work.
Then I have the following code

```
if(a.getStatus()==Status.RUNNING) a.stop();
    doStuffs();
}
```

Now I want that when `doStuff()` is called animation must not do any work.
Because `stop()` method is asynchronous (like `play()` and `jumpTo()` methods) how can I be sure that animation is really stopped?

Another think I didn't understand is when `stop()` method is called, what JavaFX Thread does? Does it set a flag to check later? At what time animation stop to do the work?

Thank you.

Comment: If your animation  use a thread ,you can get stat of your task/thread for example _interrupted_.

Comment: If you are using [`AnimationTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html), you can be sure it stops when you run the code `a.stop();`.

Comment: I'm using `javafx.animation.Timeline` a subclass of `javafx.animation.Animation`